# Shipping cost change depending on products in cart

Tags: magento-1.8

I know I should have at least attempted something before asking a question here, but I genuinely have no idea where to start.

I have my shipping rates set up and don't want these to change.  They are calculated based on the destination country.

What I want to do is keep to these rules except for when the cart contains only items from a certain category.  It would be a flat cost regardless of destination:

```
If CART contains ONLY category_id_916 THEN shipping = 2.99
ELSE follow normal rules
```

Where inside Magento would I look to implement some code like this? It could be after the system has already calculated the shipping cost if that is easier, as I can't imagine perfomance being affected too badly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ready to use module for the same https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-and-product-shipping.html or else going programmatically you will need to modify the collectRates() function which is responsible for shipping calculations.